# How does two same named identifier lead to an infinite loop in this code?

Tags: javascript

CAn anybody please explain this code from ydkjs. Topic is collision avoidance . This is an infinite loop , which i am not able to understand how ? I ran the code in sublime text editor , first output is 3 and then second output is 11 which runs infinitely .

```js
function foo() {
  function bar(a) {
    i = 3;
    console.log(a + i);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bar(i * 2);
  }
}
foo();
```

Comment: Because `i = 3;`

Answer (score 5):

When you declare a variable using `var =` , it is scoped to the entire function.  Your code is roughly equivalent to:

```js
function foo() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    i = 3;
  }
}
foo();
```

which obviously is an infinite loop, as `i` will never become `>= 10`

If you use `let i = 0`, then `i` will be scoped to the loop, so the "other" `i` inside of `bar` won't matter:

```js
function foo() {
  function bar(a) {
    i = 3;
    console.log(a + i);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bar(i * 2);
  }
}
foo();
```

Comment: Ah @dave, always too fast for me. I was also about to mention `let` before you edited. The tiny hick here is `i = 3` will bind `i` to `window`, not a huge deal but good to know